# Controlling DELETEs in Redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift

I have a Redshift database in my company (not in my power to change that) and recently some data just desapear. I thinked in do some kind of trigger to identify when any delete happen and try to found the source, but I learn Redshift don't have trigger. There are any opcions for monitoring what user and when delete from database?

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you should be having different `users` or `roles` for each and every process or client connecting to `redshift`. Use [grants](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_GRANT.html) to solve/debug this problem.
Then you should be using `grant` to provide `DELETE` grants to some specific `user/users` or `roles`.

Also, there is [sql_history](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_STL_QUERY.html) table that you could query to see which user has issued `delete` `query`.

I hope it will help.